# jQuery Script to move through the navigation bar using the keyboard right arrow key

Tags: php, jquery, html

HTML :

```
<nav id="check">
  <ul class="uk-navbar">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="uk-parent"><a href="">Information</a>
      <div class="uk-dropdown">
        <ul class="uk-nav">
          <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Events Calendar</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Forms</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Students</a></li>
    <li class="uk-parent"><a href="">Parents</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Not able to get the script right where On pressing the right arrow key I want to shift from Home to Information and then from Information to Students in the navigation bar.

My attempt:

```
jQuery("#check li").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { 
    //left
    alert('left arrow pressed!');
  }else if(e.keyCode == 39) { 
    // right
    var n= jQuery(this).attr('class');
    alert(n);

    if(n == 'uk-parent uk-open' &&  typeof n === "undefined"){
      var count= jQuery(this).index();
      //alert(count);
      var count_new= count +1;
      //alert(count_new);
      jQuery('.uk-parent').removeClass("uk-open");
      jQuery('.uk-parent').eq(count_new).addClass("uk-open");
    }
    //var m=jQuery(".uk-parent .uk-open").closest('li').next().find('li .uk-parent').addClass('uk-open');
  }
});
```

`Class="uk-open"` in the above code is used to open the `dropdown list` under `information tab`. This class is added automatically using a separate script.

Where am I going wrong with my script?

Comment: I think it fails at `n == 'uk-parent uk-open'`, because i don't see any usage of the `uk-open` CSS class in your HTML.

Comment: sir, uk-open is added automatically when you hover through the information tab. it is used to open the drop down list under that tab. so my point is when i am in the drop down list of the information tab. say for eg. i am about us. now when i press my right arrow key i want  to go to students tab, by closing the dropdown list first.

Comment: i don't think `keydown` works with `#check li`